# Will file marked as binary in GIT cause problems?

Tags: git, arcanist

I updated translations recently in a properties file and when I tried running an arc diff it came back saying there was an unknown utf-8 character and that the file would be marked as binary. I only made two changes in the file but found an Umlaut character in the file. Even after correcting that it still says there are unknown utf-8 characters and seems no matter what change I make it says it will be marked as binary.

What are the issues if I push this file? I'm guessing the file is already marked as binary since it had the umlaut in it, but wondering for my own benefit if this will cause problems? It's just a pain we can't have the file reviewed.

Comment: Is you editor using a 16 bit character set variant? Git detects 'binary' by the presence of a null byte (/0) in the byte stream. True (ideal) utf-8 never has the null byte, but some of the similar formats do.

Comment: If you push it, it will be pushed. There is no issue regarding git. If it will cause other problems is hard to say without knowing anything more about it. Maybe the editor you opened the file changed the encoding.

Comment: Where is git telling you that this is a binary file?  Can you provide a screenshot or paste of the terminal output?

Comment: If the file has already been pushed in the repository with the umlaut, you will have the warning when you try to push a fixed version of the file. This is because the warning shows up when Phabricator "diffes" the upstream and the local file